# DAX formula error - struggling to get around it

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a data set from excel (in which the analysis is all macro'd up) but want to now use this data in a power bi for a new platform I am developing/have developed on sharepoint online.

However I keep getting a formula error and cannot fathom, how to fix it.  My code is simple as below

```
Cummulative total = List.Sum(List.Range(#"Added Index"[TotalCost],0,[Index]))
```

But the error I get is below

Expression.Error: 4 arguments were passed to function which expects between 2 and 3.
Details:
Pattern=
Arguments=[List]

The formula works fine when I use it purely from the column from which my calculated column (Total Cost)  is generated, so I am thinking its the calculated column which is the issue, but this column works fine?  any Idea's as this is driving me nuts, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using List.Range? The range you are offsetting is the same as your dataset if your index is starting at 0. In that case, remove List.Range, and using only List.Sum should work.

Comment: my index starts at 1, I managed to do a work around with three calculated columns, but that's not right either.